# arithmetic overflow error for data type tinyint,value = 256

Tags: sql-server

byte number = 1;
add(number);
// form .cs

```
public static int Add( byte? order)
{
  arParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@number", (number.HasValue) ? ((object)number) : DBNull.Value);
  // stored procedure call is made which takes paramaters, 
}
```

Stored procedure looks like this

```
@number tinyint
AS
BEGIN
IF @number IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  UPDATE 
    table1
  SET 
    number = number + 1
  WHERE 
    id=13
END
INSERT INTO 
 table1
(
  number
)
VALUES 
( 
  number=@number
)
```

///////why i am getting this error can any one illustrate please and how do i solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you cannot set the [**Tinyint**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) value beyond 255 and below 0. So you should apply validation before sending it to database.

Comment: thanks , where am i passing 255 and its being set to 256. i am not sure what does  (object)number passes to storedprocedure ? and how @number is 255

Comment: It's because you are incrementing in your stored procedure. number = number + 1. Keep it 255 if the value is 255 already or you can change the datatytpe to int

Comment: ok, so it means after (object)number i am trying to assign it to tinyint the value of @number will be 255. 1 byte = 255 int is it?

Comment: You should change the datatype here as well.

Comment: now what does this mean, (thanks for your patience and support)

Comment: can you change the datatype to int from byte?

Comment: yes i can. i have final question. what will be the value of @number in the stored procdure above in my example and what will be the value of number after number + 1 in my example. (thanks for answering all my questions)

Comment: 255 in first case and 256 in second case if you choose byte

Answer (score 5):

The range of tinyint is 0-255.

You're attempting to put 256 into a datatype that doesn't know what 256 is.

[int, bigint, smalltint and tinyint ranges.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply , since i dint understood how its happening. what will be the value of @number in the storedprocedure at first and what will be the value after set number = number+1 ?

Comment: You can apply validation before sending it to database. for between 0 and 255 both are inclusive

Comment: where can i do that in codebehind?, i am still looking for the answer of this question, i have number = 1 and which is passed to storedprocedure as (object)number, in storedprocedure will the value of @number be 255?

Comment: From the code you've posted, your update query is not using the @number parameter at all.  Have you checked the 'number' field in table1?

Comment: ya i got that, will it fix my problem if i user @number in my update.

Comment: Can you change the datatype to int this can be useful in your case ?